# How do I recover/reset the postgres password?

Tags: postgresql

I have forgotten the password that I used while installing `postgres`. It asks for the password for every action I perform. What can I do in this case?

I've even tried removing postgres and reinstalling it again, but it still asks for the password.

Comment: see [Resetting password of PostgreSQL on ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588212/resetting-password-of-postgresql-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 14):

In general you can use the following procedure:
Go to the terminal and type:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

When you're logged in and the psql prompt appears then issue this SQL command:

```
ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'newpassword';
```

This may have consequences for any software using these login details too, so check if everything is still working after doing this.